# Profile picture being cached

Tags: html, django, caching, django-views

From Django i overwrite a existing photo.This photo is the profile picture of a user.I save the picture evertime as username.png on the server.So After which when the redirect is done to /home page the old picture is cached by the browser.

How to overcome this problem

return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this resource for information on how to set the cache headers.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/

Sets the Last-Modified header to the current date/time when a fresh (uncached) version of the page is requested.
Sets the Expires header to the current date/time plus the defined CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS.
Sets the Cache-Control header to give a max age for the page -- again, from the CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS setting.

Controlling these settings will ensure that the content that you don't want cached will be refreshed when the content is changed.